# text based countdown on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to run a text countdown on canvas but last I checked there was no way to write text to a canvas.

I would like to know if anyone else has come-across an implementation where I could do a numerical countdown from 60 to 0 on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var width = 200;
    var height = 200;
    $('canvas').width(width).height(height);
    var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var i = 60;
    (function draw() {
        with(ctx) {
            fillStyle = '#000';
            fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            fillStyle = '#0f0';
            font = 'bold 20px Arial';
            fillText(i, 100, 50)
            fill();
        }
        if (!(i--)) return;
        setTimeout(draw, 1000);
    })();
});
```

### [see in action](http://jsbin.com/ajice3/2)

Comment: You know `with` is considered bad form these days? (http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to draw text in canvas 2D.  If you look at the [w3c API documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/canvas-api/canvas-2d-api.html) you can see the `fillText` method on context which allows you do draw text, and the `font` property lets you control the appearance.

Do note: not all canvas 2D implementations support the text API - I know that iOS didn't do it in the past.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the wrong article... :P Seems like ur right... :D

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas) suggests that it is indeed possible to write text on a canvas.